# Copying Chart to Another Sheet with Updated References in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I have made a chart within a sheet in Excel. Within the sheet, the chart refers to specific cells in the sheet to display (i.e. cells that contain my data points).

I would like to know how to copy the chart into another sheet within my Excel file, and have the references update to refer to the cell addresses that are within the its new sheet.

Whenever you copy-paste/move a chart into another sheet, the chart will still refer to cells within the original sheet it was made in. This is because anytime you refer to a cell within a chart, it specifically refers to the sheet it was made it (i.e. Instead of saying `$T$7:$T$12`, references are made to be `SHEET'!$T$7:$T$12`).

In the references within the chart, if I change the reference from `SHEET'!$T$7:$T$12` to `$T$7:$T$12` (or even `T7:T12`), I get a message saying that my formula contains an error.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't copy the whole sheet with your data and chart?  I often do that then modify the data in the copied sheet to be what I want.

Comment: @ReyJuna Thank you! That should help me in the meantime. I was just curious as to know whether copying a chart, and updating references with it was a function somewhere within Excel, since it _could_ be more efficient, especially when working with many sheets. Anyways - thanks for the help!

Comment: I've been working with Excel for over 20 years and have not come across that function.  In the past I've thought it might be interesting to write VBA to do it, but I've never had the chance to tackle it.

Comment: @Dan, you need to create Dynamic Range where data in both sheets has similar dimension and Sheet name should be read from a Cell as variable,, Or better refer this,, https://peltiertech.com/change-series-formula-improved-routines/  ☺

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to handle this is to copy the entire worksheet with data and chart, then paste the new data into the copied worksheet. It's a simple enough protocol, if time-consuming, but there's more description in my tutorial at [Copy Chart to New Sheet and Link to Data on New Sheet](https://peltiertech.com/copy-chart-link-to-new-data/).

An alternative is to copy the chart to the new sheet use a VBA procedure to modify the series formulas in the copied chart, to replace the old sheet's name with the new sheet's name. The VBA is basically this:

```
Sub FindReplaceSeriesFormula(myChart As Chart, OldText As String, NewText As String)
  Dim srs As Series

  For Each srs In myChart.SeriesCollection
    srs.Formula = Replace(srs.Formula, OldText, NewText)
  Next
End Sub
```

and you would call it like this:

```
Sub FixActiveChart()
  FindReplaceSeriesFormula ActiveChart, "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
End Sub
```

I discuss this approach and provide some more bulletproof code in my tutorial [Change Series Formula – Improved Routines](https://peltiertech.com/change-series-formula-improved-routines/)

Comment: When I copy the entire worksheet (via the arrow icon in the top left, i.e., above 1 and to the left of A), the chart retains its data references to the old worksheet. Does this mean the only method to update the data references to the new sheet is with the macro, or am I copying the worksheet incorrectly?

Comment: To copy a sheet, right click on the sheet tab at the bottom of the window and use 'Move or Copy'. Or simply hold down Ctrl while you drag the sheet tab to the location of the new sheet. No code required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 'Excel for Dummies' way to do this.
Change the name of the source sheet so it only differs by the last character from the destination tab (eg 'sheet 2' graph and data are going to be copied  into 'sheet 1')
Put your chart and sources etc. at the top of the source sheet say rows 1 to 40.  Make a similar space in the destination sheet (we are supposing there are other items already on this sheet). Select the rows then Copy and past this across. This wont conflict with the locked cell references.
In the destination sheet edit the source data for the graph(s), which is now easy because you only need to change that one character in the sheet names, everything else will match. It should now be possible to cut and past the whole selection to somewhere else within the worksheet.
This may sound like a lot of steps but it's fairly quick and easy and reliable in the sense you control what is happening in a simple way.

If instead we cut and past the graph and data across then it automatically shifts the references without any fuss, in which case we may wish to begin by making a copy of the source tab if we want to retain it.

Answer (score 0):

I modify code for case, If you have a lot of charts:

```
Sub FindReplaceSeriesFormula(myChart As ChartObject, oldText As String, newText As String)
Dim srs As Series

    For Each srs In myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
        
        srs.Formula = Replace(srs.Formula, oldText, newText)
    
    Next
    
End Sub

Sub FixAllCharts()
Dim grph As ChartObject
Dim oldText As String, newText As String
   
    oldText = "SheetOld"
    newText = "SheetNew"
  
    For Each grph In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    
        FindReplaceSeriesFormula grph, oldText, newText
  
    Next grph
  
  
End Sub
```